# Retrieve back ONLY ONE deleted WhatsApp message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have accidentally deleted ONE message from a chat conversation and I want to retrieve it back. I have read posts and articles on how to retrieve WhatsApp messages, but it talks about whole chat or whole conversation. There are solutions such as uninstall/reinstall WhatsApp before doing a manual backup and recover data, but this does not apply to my question.

I just want to retrieve the ONLY ONE message that I deleted a couple of hours back from a chat conversation. Is this possible?

EDIT: I assume something has to be done before whatsapp takes a backup. Appreciate an early reply. Thank you.

EDIT2 : Is there any way to change the autobackup time from 4AM to 4PM?

Comment: IIRC WhatsApp takes backups daily at 3 am or something

Comment: In Settings -> Chat settings, it says 4am. Is there any tool to undelete deleted message before the auto-backup time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't take a backup after the message was received on your phone(and before it was deleted) then no you can't recover it.

Comment: I think I lost the message now. But i am still curious about what to do if this thing happens in the future. You mean there is no other way to recover that 'one single message'? There are no sofwares/tools/utilities that can recover the message before the auto-backup initiates at 4am?

Comment: Is there any way to change the autobackup time from 4AM to 4PM?

Comment: Sadly I don't think that too can be done. All you can do is make manual backups.

Comment: I have seen lot of articles that says how to recover deleted messages. You just have to take the backup of your whatsapp folder in the sdcard, uninstall and reinstall whatsapp then all messages are recovered. I tried that but I did not get that 1 important message i deleted :(